# Keyspace 'minds' does not exist

Tags: php, docker, cassandra, docker-compose, social-networking

When i try to enter the following command to build
$ docker-compose up front-build

Facing the below issue:

```
> Fatal error: Uncaught Cassandra\Exception\RuntimeException: Keyspace
> 'minds' does not exist in
> /var/www/Minds/engine/Core/Data/Cassandra/Client.php:32 Stack trace:
> #0 /var/www/Minds/engine/Core/Data/Cassandra/Client.php(32): Cassandra\DefaultCluster->connect('minds') #1
> /var/www/Minds/engine/Core/Data/DataProvider.php(37):
> Minds\Core\Data\Cassandra\Client->__construct() #2 [internal
> function]:
> Minds\Core\Data\DataProvider->Minds\Core\Data{closure}(Object(Minds\Core\Di\Di))
> #3 /var/www/Minds/engine/Core/Di/Di.php(25): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Minds\Core\Di\Di)) #4
> /var/www/Minds/engine/Core/Data/Call.php(47):
> Minds\Core\Di\Di->get('Database\Cassan...') #5
> /var/www/Minds/engine/Core/Data/Sessions.php(27):
> Minds\Core\Data\Call->__construct('session') #6
> /var/www/Minds/engine/Core/Session.php(24):
> Minds\Core\Data\Sessions->__construct() #7
> /var/www/Minds/engine/Core/Minds.php(86):
> Minds\Core\Session->__construct() #8
> /var/www/Minds/engine/start.php(23): Minds\Core\Minds->start() #9
> /var/www/Minds/engine/index. in
> /var/www/Minds/engine/Core/Data/Cassandra/Client.php on line 32
```

Please help me out

Comment: Related to [this](https://github.com/Minds/minds/issues/108) Minds issue?

Comment: Yes @JeroenHeier